# golang: convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form

Tags: go

looking to send an ipv4 address across in 4 bytes, and ipv6 address in 16 bytes - What's similar to [`inet_pton()`](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/inet_ntopman.html) in go?

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.2.33", &(sa.sin_addr));

struct sockaddr_in6 sa;
char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:8714:3a90::12", &(sa.sin6_addr));
```

I know of https://play.golang.org/p/jn8t7zJzT5v - that is looking complicated for IPV6 addresses though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[`net.ParseIP()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ParseIP) will take an IPv4 or IPv6 formatted string and return a [`net.IP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) containing the IP address.

The `net.IP` is what you'll need to feed to most other Go functions, such as to make a connection to the host.

Note that unlike most Go functions which return an error, `net.ParseIP()` simply returns `nil` if the string could not be parsed into an IP address.

https://play.golang.org/p/Cgsrgth7JKY

Comment: Also note that net.IP's underlying type is a byte slice, so for all intends and purposes it already *is* an intuitive binary representation for IP addresses.

Comment: sorry, still a bit unclear to me - how do I convert an ipv4 address to type `[4]uint8`?  https://play.golang.org/p/mCBenQAf7j1

Comment: @struggling_learner That's a bit different. And it's not very likely that you actually need to do that. What is the actual context here?

Comment: Almost like:  https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/golang/net/-/blob/dns/dnsmessage/example_test.go#L45 - need to send an ipv4 address across in 4 bytes

Comment: this! yes! thank you! if  you would it post this as an answer I would mark it as the accepted answer. (also, could you kindly include a ipv6 To16() example?)

Comment: Exactly the same but with a larger byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use the net package:
`

```
a := net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
fmt.Printf("%b %s", net.IP.To4(a))
```

`
https://play.golang.org/p/KzqYpk9OBh8

Or, you can split the IP and convert each value into an integer using strconv.Atoi(), and thereafter convert each integer into byte()

`

```
ipString := "127.0.0.1"

octets := strings.Split(ipString, ".")

octet0, _ := strconv.Atoi(octets[0])
octet1, _ := strconv.Atoi(octets[1])
octet2, _ := strconv.Atoi(octets[2])
octet3, _ := strconv.Atoi(octets[3])

b := [4]byte{byte(octet0),byte(octet1),byte(octet2),byte(octet3)}

fmt.Printf("%s has 4-byte representation of %b\n", ipString, b)
```

`
https://play.golang.org/p/2F3bC0df9wB

Comment: You can add 08 to the string interpolation to pad with zeros:
```fmt.Printf("%08b", net.IP.To4(a))```. Also the %s gives me a warning.